# Api returning odd response

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, websocket, hex

Okay so, I’m using sockets to receive data from instagram. I’ve been working on this for around a day now and this keeps happening and I can’t fix it after around 3 hours of trying. I can not show the header information since it has cookies that can be used to impersonate me but I can show the data response since I know what it should be, it’s just a bunch of hexadecimal, specifically this:

```
\x8b\x08\x00\x8b\x10\xa6^\x02\xff\xe5\x94_k\xdb0\x14\xc5\xbf\x8a\xd1s\x9bX\x8e\x1d\xc7\x860J\xe9\x06cO{\x18\x83m\\d\xf9\xdaV\xabH\x9et\xe5\xb4\x94~\xf7!'i\xd3nc\x1f`\x8f>:\xfaw~G~d\xc1\xa3cu\xf2\xc8\xc6;V'\xeb\x82Wiz\x91\xcc\xb2\x11;du\xc2\xa4\xbdC\x8d\xde\xb3\x8b\x84uAk8\rDAy\x18\x9d\x9a\x04E\x85\\\xc0\x8b\x84\x8d\xcevJ#\x8cJBp:Z\x07\xa2\xd1\xd7\xcb\xa52\x9eD\xef\xc4n\xd15F\xf0K\xbe\xe8\x8cXt\x8dl\xcd\xc2 -\xa7%\x15|\x91m6\xc5%\xaf\x96\x9cg\xf9&\xdb\xa4\xc0\xcb\x92\xf3\x92\xaf\xf3\xaa,\xd7\xab\xbc\x04\x9e\x96\xe5\xaa\xe2i\x9a\x83X\xdc\x8e\xfd;0\x12\x06\xda\xfec\xfd\xef!M\xb3u\xf4\xdaAn\xaf>|l?\x7f\xba\xedsws\xf5\xb5\xd2?\x87\xec\xcb\xc1`\x87mV\xa4\xab\\V(\xaa&\xe59\xef\xd2\x8d\xe4E\x9ea\x85U\xd6n:q4\xe2\xb6\xb8\xb9\xbe\xb9.V\xef\x8faL\xe8T\xa7\xb0eu\xd2\t\xedc\x1c\x83\xf0 \x8c5\x0f;\x1bbZ\xcf\xe1Ppx\xe6\xdba\xab\x04H\x1b\x0c\xb1:\x89\x14:\xab\xb5\xdd\xa3\xfb\x83\xa8L\xff\x17\x95\xc4\xeb\x91F\xd9\xde\x89qx8!{\x16`\xafh
```

I know it isn’t my code since it’s retuning 200 ok, and giving me valid headers. I can’t convert this text from hexadecimal to text. It just gives me random chars or weird chars. Is there any reason? I’m using an ssl socket and the endpoint is : `I.instagram.com/api/v1/users/username goes here/usernameinfo/`
And it’s a get req. Any reason I am getting hexadecimal that’s not convertible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like GZIP-compressed data, with the first byte missing which I'd expect to be `1F`. This is an educated guess because `1F 8B 08` is the header of GZIP and unexpected compression is often the source of this sort of surprise.

Check the `Content-Encoding` header in the response, I bet it is `gzip`.

You can try sending a request header `Accept-Encoding: identity` to say that the only encoding you'd accept is `identity` (which is no encoding at all). It's possible that the webserver ignores that though, in that case you'd have to [decompress the response yourself](https://gist.github.com/Garrett-R/dc6f08fc1eab63f94d2cbb89cb61c33d).